# Amasty One Step Checkout and Klarna Checkboxes

Tags: amasty, klarna

I have a question regarding flexboxes. I use the amasty one step checkout, beside that I want to offer payment by klarna. The problem here is, that the original payment choices are flexboxes but the checkboxes for klarna are not. This results in a silly experience. To choose one of the klarna payment options, I have to click in the area of the logo. (label klarna-payments-method-cell)
The normal / original payments are clickable through the whole contianer, cause it´s a flex-element. Wondering where I have to make adjustments to make the klarna checkboxes to flex-elements. Amasty or Klarna files, custom css in the theme files?? Sorry for the inconvenience, Although I am an IT Guy, I am absolutely bad at programming, more the cloud/infrastructure/DB guy.

[image: Klarna div]

[image: Original payment method]

[image: Klarna Cell]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Klarna Css was responsible for this.

So I´ve done the following:

Create the module folder in your theme folder:

app/design/frontend/VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/Klarna_Kp/web/css/source/

Create a `_extend.less` file in there with the following content:

```
.klarna-payments-method-cell {
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: I've improve your answer to make it correct by use `_extend.less` instead of `_module.less`. If you use `_module.less`, your file will override the CSS from `_module.less` of the Klarna_Kp extension, and cause the CSS from `_module.less` of theKlarna_Kp extension getting lost.

Comment: Please mark your answer as **accepted**, that indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.

Comment: I thought _module.less would be the correct option since .klarna-payments-method-cell already exists and it should be overwritten. 

Wouldn't the code then exist twice?

I actually ask to be able to understand it.

Comment: You can read more about _override.less and _extend.less from the Magento official document https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/css/quickstart/customize-styles/

Comment: _modules.less in your theme will replace the content of Klarna_Kp extension's _module.less file then Klarna_Kp extension's _module.less file will be lost if you did not copy all content of that file to your _module.less file. In your case, you should use _extend.less instead of _module.less which allows you to extend the parent's CSS file but not need to override the whole file of the parent .less file which helps your code easily maintained.